# передавать данные в соответствии с установленными на данный момент фильтрами в таблицу эксель и скачивать ее только с актуальными данными React

Tags: reactjs, excel

Есть таблица с фильтрами на странице - они работают, а также есть кнопка скачивания таблицы excel с данными, но сейчас скачивается вся информация (даже если стоят фильтры - они не учитываются и в таблицу эксель попадает полный неотфильтрованный список), как сделать так, чтобы туда попадали только отфильтрованные данные, подскажите, пожалуйста?

использую здесь saveAs from 'file-saver'и downloadBlob

в ссылке на api должны появиться пропсы текущей страницы (как в адресной строке)

```html
   
export const exportPolicies = async ({
  userRole,
  type,
  dateFrom,
  dateTo,
}: ExportPoliciesInput) => {
  const params: ExportPoliciesRequestPayload = { type };
  if (dateFrom) {
    params.from = dateFrom;
  }
  if (dateTo) {
    params.to = dateTo;
  }

  const response = await api.get<Blob>(
    `${userRole}/insurance-policies/export`,
    {
      params,
      responseType: 'blob',
    }
  );

  const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/zip' });
  saveAs(blob, `policies_${dayjs().format('DD-MM-YYYY_HH-mm-ss')}.xlsx`);
};

export const startPaymentCheck = async ({
  id
}: PaymentCheckInput) => {
  const body = {
    offer_id: id,
  }
  const response = await api.post(
    'admin/insurance-policies/request-start-payment-check',
    body
  )

  return response.data
}
```

Comment: Выложите плз больше кода, в таком изолированном контексте не понятно как вам подсказать. Как вариант загрузите часть проекта на github в открытый репозиторий и расшарьте тут  ссылку. Думаю смогу помочь вам

Comment: @ioszhuk было бы очень здорово! загрузила полный файл!)) если этого будет тоже недостаточно -скажите, пожалуйста)

Comment: это тоже изолированно) я же не смогу полноценно воспроизвести его. Вам нужно создать реакт проект с нуля и вложить в него все что нужно конкретно для этой страницы с фильтрами и таблицей